# Append white space to file during bcp export

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcp

I am working on a program which loads a bunch of files in a SQL database with an average amount of rows totaling over 150,000 + records into a table and then a process runs to match SSN numbers based on how many times an SSN shows up in the table. Once the process is finished running, those 150,000 + records are then exported to a text file which we then send to a company for processing. I am using the BCP (Bulk Copy) utility with a format file to load the records into the table and to export the processed records to the text file at the end of the process.

The problem I am facing is the file export produces the records we want but the character count is off as each record within the file is only 99 characters long when it should be 102 characters log. With the additional characters missing the company we send the file to can not process it on their end.

My question is, how can I add the additional white space without adding too many additional steps to my current process as it is a bit resource intensive. My first thought is to amend the current format file I am using to include three additional white spaces at the end of each row, but in reading comments over the internet I am not sure this is possible. My next thought was to loop through each of the rows in the text file to add the additional white space, but that seems a bit inefficient as it would be easier to add the white spaces while the file export occurs instead of looping through all the records as I am sure that is quite resource intensive. What would be the best approach?

```
Format File
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="14" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="9" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="9" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="16" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH='6' TERMINATOR="\n" />
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Agency" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Fund" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Account" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="LName" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="FName" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="SSN" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Prior" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="BalDue" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="DRSBal" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="Fill1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="FileDate" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
</ROW>
</BCPFORM>
```

Stored Procedure which processes the file export

```
DECLARE @fileName varchar(75) = 'ITAS_FILENAME';
  DECLARE @processTime varchar(14) = REPLACE(Convert(varchar, getdate(), 108), ':', '');
  DECLARE @processDate varchar(8) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112);
  DECLARE @bulkCopyCmd varchar(512);
  DECLARE @filePath varchar(100) = 'E:\DRSFILE\OUT\';

   SET @fileName = @fileName + @processDate + @processTime + '.txt';
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 

    -- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE

    -- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1

    -- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE

   SET @bulkCopyCmd = 'bcp "Execute dbo.sp_process_file_export "processResult"" queryout "'
                    + @filePath 
                    + @fileName + '"'
                    + ' -S [Server IP] -T -d "DRSFile" -f "E:\DRSFILE\Utilites\drsFile_SQL_FormatFile.xml"'

    --Insert File Details
   INSERT INTO FileExportDetails (userName, fileName, runDate)
    VALUES (@userName, @fileName, @processDate + @processTime)

    --Run Bulk Copy Command
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bulkCopyCmd

 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        --Error, something went wrong
      SET @processResults = 0
    ELSE
            --Success
      SET @processResults = 1
```

Comment: Possibly it's a string truncation issue, not lack of white space. Should `FileDate` really only output 6 characters? As in yyymm?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes the file date is six characters yy mm dd which is the standard for the company we send the file to. I am re writing this program and the current file format does account for those additional white spaces. Do you know if it is possible to add additional white space Via bulk export using a file format file? I've also read in c# there is a function padRight() which can also accomplish this goal but I rather not add an additional step.

Comment: Your format file is telling BCP to create a line of 99 bytes. Just set your query and format to create data of larger size. Your total in the format file is 99 bytes... that's why you are getting a 99-byte line. I assume you have a file spec from your stakeholder? Which of your fields are short of what they expect?

Comment: @jamie yes this is a fixed with file. The records are correct in that I am not missing data I just need to add additional filler space 3 characters worth.

Comment: This does not make sense. You are saying the file is accurately created as 99 bytes, but then also that it is not accurately created as 102 bytes. I can add an answer to just add a 3 byte field at the end, but something is not adding up. Does the receiving company have a document detailing the layout of the line they want? I would think it has either an additional field that you are missing (a "filler" as you say) or that the last field should be 9 bytes and not 6. Can you share the layout from their documentation?

Comment: @jamie sorry for the confusion. When I say I am not missing data I'm referring to the actual text characters which end at the date field not the additional white spaces I need to add to meet the 102 character quota. As for documentation, I'll have to wait until Monday when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Understood, if you know now that there is simply one field to be added to the end of the layout then that is enough info to answer with. To be clear then, the line should not end at where you are ending it (Filedate). It sounds like there is another field that should also be there (Filler). It's very common to have a filler of empty space and although it has no data it is still very much part of the layout. thanks for clarifying. i'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another field to your format file and query.

To your query, just add a new last column

```
select
    col_a
,   col_b
,   ...
,   Filedate
,   cast( '' as char( 3 ) ) Fill2 -- add this new column
from your_table
```

Then also add to your format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="14" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="9" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="9" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="16" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="6" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH='3' TERMINATOR="\n" />
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Agency" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Fund" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Account" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="LName" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="FName" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="SSN" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Prior" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="BalDue" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="DRSBal" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="Fill1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="FileDate" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
<COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="Fill2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
</ROW>
</BCPFORM>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot.